# Choice principles and Ramsey's theorem.

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, ramsey-theory

I was reading Ramsey theory and wanted to know which choice principle was equivalent to infinite Ramsey theorem (by which I mean "For all $n,k \in \mathbb N$ and for all infinite sets $Z$, every $n$-colouring of $k$-tuples of $Z$ has an infinite homogeneous subset.") .

I know that countable choice implies Ramsey's theorem, and even Ramsey's theorem for pairs in two colours implies Kőnig's lemma (and hence countable choice for finite sets) over ZF, but I do not know about the other directions.

There is a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465064/connection-trees-and-partition) that claims Kőnig's lemma implies Ramsey's theorem, but I am not sure if it is correct, thank you.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Same as this except for an arbitrary infinite set instead of just integers.

Comment: I believe the connection between Ramsey and choice was first studied by Eugene Kleinberg [The independence of Ramsey's theory.  J. Symbolic Logic 34 (1969), 205–206.] I aded more information about that in [Ramsey's theorem in the hierarchy of choice principles.  J. Symbolic Logic 42 (1977), no. 3, 387–390.]

Comment: @NoahSchweber Sorry, fixed it.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thank you, I will read it.

Comment: @AndreasBlass So as far as I understand Kőnig's lemma is strictly weaker than Ramsey's theorem and there is no particular choice principle which is equivalent to Ramsey's theorem, am I correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Andreas Blass pointed in the comments to his paper

> *Blass, Andreas*, [**Ramsey’s theorem in the hierarchy of choice principles**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2272866), J. Symb. Log. 42(1977), 387-390 (1978). [ZBL0374.02037](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0374.02037).

In that paper he shows that in Cohen's first model, if $A$ is the set of generic Cohen reals, which is Dedekind-finite there, then $F({a,b})=\min(a\mathop{\triangle}b)\pmod 2$ is a colouring without an infinite homogeneous subset.

Indeed, if $B$ was homogeneous, let $\dot B$ be a name for it, and $E$ a finite support for $\dot B$ and for some $p$ such that $p\Vdash``\dot B$ is homogeneous for $\dot F"$. Extend $p$ to $q$ which decides that some $\dot a_n\in\dot B$ for some $n\notin E$, let $m$ be an integer not mentioned in $q$ or $E$.

We consider $q'$ to be $q$ with the information that $q'(m,i)=q(n,i)$ for all $i$ on which $q(n,i)$ was defined. It is easy to see that the $2$-cycle $(m\ n)$ is a permutation of $\omega$ which fixes $E$ pointwise, and indeed $q'$ is not moved. Therefore, $q'\Vdash\dot a_m\in\dot B$ as well. But since we did not decide yet the value of $\dot F(\{\dot a_m,\dot a_n\}^\bullet)$, we can throw a wrench into the whole $\dot B$ is homogeneous.

Why did we do all of that? Well, in Cohen's first model every set can be linearly ordered. So given a finitely branching tree of height $\omega$, by induction each level is finite, linearly ordering the underlying set we get a uniform enumeration of the levels, and therefore a proof that the tree is countable. Therefore, it has a branch.

It is worth noting that Kőnig's lemma is equivalent to any of the four formulations found in "Every countable/infinite family of finite sets admits a [partial] choice function" (the partial means an infinite subfamily with a choice function).

---

Now, it seems that at the same time as Andreas was working on his paper, Gabriele Lolli published

> *Lolli, Gabriele*, [**On Ramsey’s theorem and the axiom of choice**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1305/ndjfl/1093888126), Notre Dame J. Formal Logic 18, 599-601 (1977). [ZBL0351.02041](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0351.02041).

Where he incorrectly claims that the equivalence does in fact hold. To quote the [Math Review](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=491198) by Robert Cowen, "the proofs given are not convincing."

This is further addressed by Eleftherios Tachtsis in his paper. Which also contain some relevant results.

> *Tachtsis, Eleftherios*, [**On Ramsey’s theorem and the existence of infinite chains or infinite anti-chains in infinite posets**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/jsl.2015.47), J. Symb. Log. 81, No. 1, 384-394 (2016). [ZBL1342.03036](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1342.03036).

Finally, John Truss in a paper that followed by a paper joint with Thomas Forester studied Kőnig's lemma and Ramsey theorem, and it seems that they should be mentioned here.

> *Truss, J.*, Some cases of Konig’s lemma, Set Theory Hierarchy Theory, Mem. Tribute A. Mostowski, Bierutowice 1975, Lect. Notes Math. 537, 273-284 (1976). [ZBL0338.02039](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0338.02039).
>
> *Forster, T. E.; Truss, J. K.*, [**Ramsey’s theorem and König’s lemma**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00153-006-0025-z), Arch. Math. Logic 46, No. 1, 37-42 (2007). [ZBL1114.03038](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1114.03038).