# A question regarding the upward implications between versions of the infinite Ramsey theorem over $\sf ZF$.

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, ramsey-theory

Let ${\sf RT}^n_k$ denote the statement "For all infinite sets $Z$ and functions $c : [Z]^n \to k$, there is an infinite subset $H$ of $Z$ such that $c$ is constant on $[H]^n$.”.

The infinite Ramsey theorem states that "For all $n,k \in \mathbb N^+$, ${\sf RT}^n_k$ holds.". It is [well-known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4240184/choice-principles-and-ramseys-theorem) that Ramsey's theorem implies Kőnig's lemma over $\sf ZF$, so some form of choice is necessary to prove it (for example, "Every Dedekind-finite set is finite." suffices).

In the [paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00153-006-0025-z) by Forster and Truss, the authors show that the statements ${\sf RT}^n_k$ are all equivalent for all $k \in \mathbb N \setminus \{0,1\}$, where $n$ is fixed, over $\sf ZF$. More interestingly, they also show that (with a very interesting proof) for all $n_1,n_2,k_1,k_2 \in \mathbb N$, where $n_1 \geq n_2 \geq 1$ and $k_1,k_2 > 1$, we have ${\sf RT}^{n_1}_{k_1} \implies {\sf RT}^{n_2}_{k_2}$, over $\sf ZF$.

However, the authors point out that they were unable to show the reverse implications (the upward implications for the upper index) over $\sf ZF$, and they also note that they think these implications are unlikely to hold.

My question is: Are there any new results regarding these reverse implications? Thank you.